# Can't disinstall Intel(®) Centrino(®) Wireless-N 100

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter, intel-centrino

I need to disinstall Intel(®) Centrino(®) Wireless-N 130,
but when I try to disinstall it, nothing appens:

ComputerManagement -> Device Manager -> Network Adapters -> Right-Click on Centrino -> Disintall

I maded a lot of attempts, also in different ways but I can't disinstall it...

I've downloaded the new driver from the Intel.com website: `Wireless_16.11.0_s64.exe`

But when I launch it, a blue setup window says: "Cant remove previous version, unistall it manually"

Please help...